# Require a gem only in the context of a single class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, timeout, require

I have written a gem that *uses* a [gem](http://code.jjb.cc/2012/09/15/sane_timeout-a-replacement-for-rubys-standard-library-timeout/) in one of its classes to overwrite `Timeout`. I only want to overwrite `Timeout` in this single instance, not globally in my gem and certainly not globally in anyone's project that uses my gem.

The problem I'm running into is when I include *my* gem in a rails project. It seems that the timeout gem gets instantiated from the get-go (at rails app load) and affects other parts of my Rails app that rely on the standard `Timeout`.

My question is this: how can I limit the timeout gem's influence to only the single class that I wish to use it in. I've already placed the `require` statement within the class definition and this didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `require: false` in your Gemfile. E.g.:

```
 gem 'name-of-gem', require: false
```

That way the gem won't be required automatically on app load, only when you explicitly call `require 'name-of-gem'` in your model.

(If that gives you errors you may be using an older version of Ruby, so you'll have to write `:require => false` instead of `require: false`)

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fork this gem and add a namespace to Timeout module like this:

```
require "timeout"
module NewTimeout
  module Timeout
    #overwrited stuff
  end
end
```

And then use it in your gem directly:
NewTimeout::Timeout.timeout()
Or include in your class:

```
class SomeClass
  include NewTimeout::Timeout
end
```

And default Timeout module left unchanged

Comment: This wasn't the correct answer to the question, but from an architectural point of view I agree with you. Changing the behavior of a core function probably isn't the best idea, and it should be broken out into a new namespace.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible without cooperation of the gem author.

When you `require` a file, the code in the file gets run. Period. If the code in the file monkeypatches a class or modifies the global namespace or whatever, that will happen. Period.

You can use `load` instead of `require` which allows you to evaluate the file within the context of an anonymous module. But, of course, using the namespace operator `::` the code in the file can *still* get access to the global namespace and every module and class in it, by just doing something like `class ::String; def length; 42 end end`.

Now, if the gem author published his gem as a `refine`ment, then you would *at least* be able to limit the effects to a single script body:

`string_with_upper_reverse.rb`:

```
module UpperReverse
  def reverse
    super.upcase
  end
end

module StringWithUpperReverse
  refine String do
    prepend UpperReverse
  end
end

puts 'Hello'.reverse
# olleH

using StringWithUpperReverse

puts 'Hello'.reverse
# OLLEH
```

`test.rb`:

```
puts 'Hello'.reverse
# olleH

require_relative 'string_with_upper_reverse'

puts 'Hello'.reverse
# olleH

using StringWithUpperReverse

puts 'Hello'.reverse
# OLLEH

require_relative 'required'
```

`required.rb`:

```
puts 'Hello'.reverse
# olleH

using StringWithUpperReverse

puts 'Hello'.reverse
# OLLEH
```

As you can see, neither `require`ing nor being `require`d by a script which is `using` the `refine`ment will mean that the `refine`ment is visible inside your script. *Only* explicitly `using` the `refine`ment inside a script body will make the `refine`ment visible *only* from that point on and *only* within that *one* script body.

Note, however, that `refine`ments are an experimental feature: their API may change without notice in future versions of Ruby, they may even be removed altogether.

Note also that the version of `refine`ments that ships with Ruby 2.0.0 (and also current development versions of Ruby 2.1) can *only* be scoped to script bodies. The ability to be scoped to `module` and `class` bodies was removed shortly prior to the release of Ruby 2.0.0, together with the `Module#using` method.

And lastly, note that `Object#send` ignores `refine`ments:

```
require_relative 'string_with_upper_reverse'

using StringWithUpperReverse

puts 'Hello'.reverse
# OLLEH

puts 'Hello'.send(:reverse)
# olleH
```

Comment: Great information on `refine`. It looks like @GeorgeMillo was able to limit the scope of the gem's influence in my scenario though. This may be because the part of my Rails app that uses the gem is a separate daemon, so it isn't executed in the core rails MVC space.